# .onAppear function only gets called when user logs in

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have this view with a tabView that has an .onAppear modifier. However, that function only gets called if the user logs in, if they are already logged in the function won't get called. Any clue where I should put it instead or why it is not working?

```
var body: some View {
            
            //If NOT logged in
            if model.loggedIn == false {
                //Show Login view
                LoginView()
                    .onAppear {
                        //Check if user is logged in
                        model.checkLogin()
                    }
            } else {
                //Show logged in view (A.K.A. = HOME)

                TabView {
                    //Home View
                    HomeView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "book")
                                Text("Learn")
                            }
                        }
                    
                    //Profile View
                    ProfileView()
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: "person")
                                Text("Profile")
                            }
                        }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    model.getChapters()
                }
            }
   
}
```

Comment: Which is the onAppear that you think isn't called?

Comment: Wrap everything in a `VStack` or even a `Group` and then use `onAppear { model.checkLogin() }` on that.

Comment: @matt the one at the bottom